# My other operating system has vanished even after running boot-repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lubuntu

After installing Lubuntu, I have never found a dual boot option, so I ran boot-repair.

I've got 2 updates and one is good and the other is extremely bad:

*The Good One*: I can see the dual boot options now.

*The Bad One*: I can't see my other operating system, it's just Ubuntu.

Output of `parted --list`

[image: The output of the command parted --list]

Here is the output of the commands:

```
sudo os-prober
sudo update-grub
```

[image]

Comment: Could you boot into either your Lubuntu or Boot-Repair live CD, run `parted --list` as root and add the output to your question?

Comment: I can't copy past the output, and can't upload a screen-shot because I have to have 10 points of reputation first, when I have them, i'll upload it :)

Comment: it's my good luck, somebodies are favouring this post, so I got many reputation points, and could finally upload that photo

Comment: Could you clarify what you meant by being able to "see the dual boot options", but not being able to "see my other operating system"?

Comment: Usually as I remember, in the dual boot, there are 5 choices to choose from, the first 4 choices are all ubuntu, and the fifth is the other operating system, I cant see the fifth choice (the other system) so I can't access it at all

Comment: Could you run `gparted` and set the boot flag on `/dev/sda5` and then reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command to detect other operating systems:

```
sudo os-prober
```

and then this to update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I adjoined the output in a picture to the question ..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by formatting my device and then installed windows xp and ubuntu instead of windows 7 and lubuntu, since lubuntu has that kind of problems ..